# GLSL Array Not Working

Tags: java, arrays, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I've been trying to create a fragment shader, but I've been having a lot of trouble with creating a simple array of vec2 constants. I've looked everywhere and tried everything I could find, like these:

```
const vec2 poisson16[16] = vec2[](vec2( -0.94201624,  -0.39906216 ),
                            vec2(  0.94558609,  -0.76890725 ),
                            vec2( -0.094184101, -0.92938870 ),
                            vec2(  0.34495938,   0.29387760 ),
                            ...some other vec2's...
                            vec2( -0.81409955,   0.91437590 ),
                            vec2(  0.19984126,   0.78641367 ),
                            vec2(  0.14383161,  -0.14100790 ) );
```

but it would print:

```
ERROR: 0:23: ']' : syntax error syntax error 
ERROR: 0:38: ';' : syntax error syntax error
```

I also tried:

```
const vec2 poisson16[16] = {    vec2( -0.94201624,  -0.39906216 ),
                            vec2(  0.94558609,  -0.76890725 ),
                            vec2( -0.094184101, -0.92938870 ),
                            vec2(  0.34495938,   0.29387760 ),
                            ...some more vec2's...
                            vec2( -0.81409955,   0.91437590 ),
                            vec2(  0.19984126,   0.78641367 ),
                            vec2(  0.14383161,  -0.14100790 ) };
```

but that would return:

```
ERROR: 0:22: '{' : syntax error syntax error
```

The shader giving the error is the fragment shader. I'm using java with LWJGL in my program, and using ARB extensions for the shaders. The setup I'm using for the shaders is copied straight from http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=GLSL_Shaders_with_LWJGL. I simply could not find a way to fix this, everything I tried ended up in an error. Maybe it's a problem with the shader setup?

Comment: BTW, what I'm trying to make of the shaders is simple SSAO shading. If you have any SSAO shaders of your own, posting it will be just as great as fixing my array problem.

Comment: Where's your `#version` directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GLSL 1.20 spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf), section 3.3, "Preprocessor", page 14:

> Version 1.10 of the language does not require shaders to include this directive [`#version`], and **shaders that do not include a #version directive will be treated as targeting version 1.10.**

So since you don't specify a `#version` directive your GLSL is assumed to be `#version 110`.

Thus, from the [GLSL 1.10 spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.10.59.pdf), section 4.1.9, "Arrays", page 27:

> There is no mechanism for initializing arrays at declaration time from within a shader.

You can do what you want using `#version 120` and above though.